# Complete graph invariant

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism, graph-invariants

Does anybody know whether the multiset of the determinants (possibly together with the order of the submatrix they refer to) of all the principal minors of the (symmetric) adjacency matrix of a graph is a complete invariant for graph isomorphism (i.e. that multiset uniquely identifies a graph up to isomorphism)?

Thanks!

Comment: cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14147/complete-graph-invariant

Answer (score 1):

The  answer is no. A counterexample is given by the following two graphs both having $(-1,
 -1,
 -1,
 -1,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 0,
 1)
$ as the multiset that you describe.

[image]

[image]

If you want to play further, you can use the following Sage program that found them

```
def tupleDet(G):
    A = G.am()
    L =  []  
    for sub in subsets(range(G.order())):    
        D = A.matrix_from_rows_and_columns(sub,sub)
        L.append(D.det())

    return tuple(sorted(L))    


def search(n):
    d= {}
    for G in graphs.nauty_geng(str(n)):
        des = tupleDet(G)
        if des in d:
            print G.graph6_string(), d[des]
            return
        else:
            d[des] = G.graph6_string()
```

Comment: It is only necessary to consider pairs of cospectral graphs. This could speed up any search - first get pairs of cospectral graphs, then check the refined invariant.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil In this case one just has to change in the above code : graphs.nauty_geng(str(n)): to graphs.cospectral_graphs(n)